# Wasn't 009's car tracked in Spectre?

Tags: james-bond, spectre

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T93T9Udh_5s) scene in Skyfall, Bond mentioned that the “Trouble with company cars is: they have trackers”. In Spectre, [after Bond asks Q to temporarily disable his smart blood](https://youtu.be/T3O1lApvhRQ?t=74), he immediately steals 009’s car which I imagine, would have trackers I mean, [it was a fully equipped MI6 car](https://youtu.be/8sB61WEinsI?t=193) so... Am I correct in assuming this was just a mistake?

Comment: It certainly wasn't fully equipped as is evident from the problems Bond has with it.

Comment: We aren't told when 009 was due to collect his new motor. Maybe when Q realised it was missing, he may have been in too deep to mention it and have a light shone on his treason in assisting Bond get away, so he was disabled or failed to mention he'd lost the motor as well. Stack bad moves on top of more bad moves.